# VBA Array Sort with Fieldname as Parameter

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

Here's the deal...In trying to get past my fear of Class Modules in Excel VBA, I decided to create a class that is an array, then add  functions (methods) for adding elements, sorting an instance, etc.  Those are things I keep re-writing in normal modules as functions/subs but hope use of classes might be a step forward.

Code Module

```
Public Type Thing
   Name As String
   SomeNumber As Double
End Type
```

Class Module

```
Private pSomething() As Thing
```

This is followed by all the usual Public LETs and GETs, plus a function for inserting new values into the array.  Then I get to the sorting function/method.  There is no problem with sorting by Name or SomeNumber, but so far that takes two function/methods.  I would like to parameterize into a single function/mehod then use an optional parameter to control which field is to be used.  The following works, but it seems a bit clunky

```
Function SortByField(Optional FieldName As String, Optional SortOrder As vbaSortOrder)
    Dim strTemp As Thing
    If SortOrder = 0 Then SortOrder = soBottomToTop
    If Len(FieldName) = 0 Then FieldName = "Name"
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim lngMin As Long
    Dim lngMax As Long
    lngMin = LBound(pSomething)
    lngMax = UBound(pSomething)
    For i = lngMin To lngMax - 1
      For j = i + 1 To lngMax
        If IIf(SortOrder = soBottomToTop, _
                              IIf(FieldName = "Name", pSomething(i).Name > pSomething(j).Name, _
                                                       pSomething(i).SomeNumber > pSomething(j).SomeNumber), _
                              IIf(FieldName = "Name", pSomething(i).Name < pSomething(j).Name, _
                                                       pSomething(i).SomeNumber < pSomething(j).SomeNumber)) _
                              Then
          strTemp = pSomething(i)
          pSomething(i) = pSomething(j)
          pSomething(j) = strTemp
        End If
      Next j
    Next i
End Function
```

What I would like to do is replace the following (and it's peer in the second part of this gawdawful IF(IIF...) nonsense

```
IIf(FieldName = "Name", pSomething(i).Name > pSomething(j).Name, pSomething(i).SomeNumber > pSomething(j).SomeNumber)
```

...with something like this

```
"pSomething(i)." & FieldName > "pSomething(j)." & FieldName
```

Direct Question: How do I get the string to evaluate/convert to code?

Indirect Question:  Is there some other technique to pass in a fieldname and have it treated as something other than a string?

Thanks in advance for any help, assistance, guidance, direction, references, advice this is a fool's errand, or derisive comments :).

Answer (score 3):

BiggerDon,
I was trying to follow your code and you are right the nested IIF are gawdawful. Can I suggest that you rewrite the code with SELECT CASE statements. That might help a bit.
Further, what is the big objective you are trying to achieve?  This almost looks like overkill for a single dimension array.

There might be other Excel VBA built in methods you can capitalize on.

I just did a quick internet search on sorting Arrays and came across Pearson's website http://www.cpearson.com/excel/SortingArrays.aspx

You might what to check it out.

Comment: I can't resist upvoting. You linked to Chip Pearson's site.

Comment: @Fred...Thanks.  I'm a regular visitor to Chip Pearson's excellent site and I've learned a lot there.

Comment: @Fred...Sorry, cut myself off before I finished then took too long to complete the edits.
 
Unfortunately, MS doesn't treat arrays as objects, so there are no methods to exploit.  I've considered the Select Case technique, too, but it doesn't get me where I want to go.

What I'm trying to do is come up with a re-usable sort function/method that I can plug into any arrayed class without going through the hassle of either having a different sort method for each field I might need (It's not hard work.  I feel it junks up class.) or need to re-write select/use based on each Class's fields.

Answer (score 1):

@BiggerDon,
How about a custom type class with a property for each of your fields.
Loop through the records and add them to a collection of the custom class. When you do this you determine which field will be used as the key for the collection.
Then use something like presented here.
[How do I sort a collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587662/how-do-i-sort-a-collection)

Comment: I've gone through a similar exercise using Collections, mainly because  one can select using a value for the key field, e.g. Sheets(<sheetname>).

I'm pretty tied into using complex types for these problems, e.g.

Type X

 Name as String

 StartDate as Date

End Type.

With the example you've linked I would expect at least two more fields, i.e Price & Number on Hand.  At different points I want the list by alpha , by price, or by units on hand.

I can write three separate sorts.  No sweat. Now I'm trying to write one sort function/method/sub with a parameter pointing to which field to key on.

Answer (score 0):

Consider an approach based on custom classes instead of types, and using `Eval()` method from VBScript to evaluate item's field value.

Place the code below in **VBA Module**:

```
Sub TestStorage()
    Dim Room As New Storage
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Elem As Object
    Dim Item As Variant
    Dim Result As String

    For i = 1 To 10
        Set Elem = New OrdinalType
        Elem.Name = GetRandomFruit
        Elem.Index = i
        Room.Push Elem
    Next
    For i = 11 To 20
        Set Elem = New ExtendedType
        Elem.Name = GetRandomFruit
        Elem.Index = i
        Elem.Additional = "Extended"
        Room.Push Elem
    Next
    Set Elem = Nothing

    ShowList Room.GetContent

    Room.SortByField "Name", True
    ShowList Room.GetContent

    Room.SortByField "Index", False
    ShowList Room.GetContent

End Sub

Sub ShowList(Arr)
    Result = ""
    For Each Item In Arr
        Result = Result & Item.Name & " (" & Item.Index & ")"
        If TypeName(Item) = "ExtendedType" Then
            Result = Result & " " & Item.Additional
        End If
        Result = Result & vbCrLf
    Next
    MsgBox Result
End Sub

Function GetRandomFruit()
    Dim Fruits
    Randomize
    Fruits = Array("Apple", "Apricot", "Banana", "Bilberry", "Blackberry", "Blackcurrant", "Blueberry", "Coconut", "Currant", "Cherry", "Cherimoya", "Clementine", "Date", "Damson", "Durian", "Elderberry", "Fig", "Feijoa", "Gooseberry", "Grape", "Grapefruit", "Huckleberry", "Jackfruit", "Jambul", "Jujube", "Kiwifruit", "Kumquat", "Lemon", "Lime", "Loquat", "Lychee", "Mango", "Mangostine", "Melon", "Cantaloupe", "Honeydew", "Watermelon", "Rock melon", "Nectarine", "Orange", "Passionfruit", "Peach", "Pear", "Plum", "Prune", "Pineapple", "Pomegranate", "Pomelo", "Raisin", "Raspberry", "Rambutan", "Redcurrant", "Satsuma", "Strawberry", "Tangerine", "Ugli Fruit")
    GetRandomFruit = Fruits(LBound(Fruits) + Round(Rnd * (UBound(Fruits) - LBound(Fruits))))
End Function
```

Add reference to **Microsoft Script Control** ActiveX (Menu - Tools - References).
Place the code below in **VBA Class Module**, Name `Storage`:

```
Private Content As Variant
Private SC As MSScriptControl.ScriptControl

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set SC = New MSScriptControl.ScriptControl
    SC.Language = "VBScript"
    SC.ExecuteStatement "Function EvalProp(Item, Name): EvalProp = Eval(""Item."" & Name): End Function"
    Content = Array()
End Sub

Private Function GetValue(ObjectInstance, PropertyName)
    GetValue = SC.Run("EvalProp", ObjectInstance, PropertyName)
End Function

Public Sub Push(Item)
    ReDim Preserve Content(UBound(Content) + 1)
    Set Content(UBound(Content)) = Item
End Sub

Public Function Pop()
    Set Pop = Content(UBound(Content))
    ReDim Preserve Content(UBound(Content) - 1)
End Function

Public Sub SortByField(Optional PropName As String = "Name", Optional SortAsc As Boolean = True)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim l As Long
    Dim u As Long
    Dim a As Variant
    Dim b As Variant
    Dim tmp As Object
    l = LBound(Content)
    u = UBound(Content)
    For i = l To u - 1
        For j = i + 1 To u
            a = GetValue(Content(i), PropName)
            b = GetValue(Content(j), PropName)
            If (a > b And SortAsc) Or (a < b And Not SortAsc) Then
                Set tmp = Content(j)
                Set Content(j) = Content(i)
                Set Content(i) = tmp
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub

Public Function GetContent()
    GetContent = Content
End Function

Public Function GetSize()
    GetSize = UBound(Content) - LBound(Content) + 1
End Function
```

Place the code below in **VBA Class Module**, Name `OrdinalType`:

```
Public Name As String
Public Index As Double
```

Place the code below in **VBA Class Module**, Name `ExtendedType`:

```
Public Name As String
Public Index As Double
Public Additional As String
```

This example shows how to create and store the instances of different types in the storage object which is able to process those types, in this particular case - to sort them taking a string as a sort field name. Note that such VBS injection is abnormal and generally it's not a best practice. Regarding processing speed - `Function GetValue()` call takes about 15 mksecs on my N7110.

Comment: By jove, omegastripes, I think you've pointed me in the right direction.  Thanks much.

Like I intimated, I'm fairly new to creating custom Classes.  I'll need to take some time to study through this (I'm not much on copy-paste what I don't understand) and see what I can do with it.  One last thing...there are some great concepts from my past (I was a non-programmer for decades and just started re-learning a few years ago) in there for me to re-internalize, like using Pop/Push.