# VBA: how to sort cell data on the basis Font color

Tags: excel, vba, string, sorting, cell

I have a data string in the cell as

[image]

I want to sort the string on the basis of Font Color such as

[image]

Possible to write in a VBA code. Thanks

```
Range("S37").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add(Range("S37:S37"), _
    xlSortOnFontColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(0, 102 _
    , 0)
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Sort
    .SetRange Range("S37:S37")
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Comment: `Sort` method is not for sorting content of one cell. It is for sorting a Range. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.sort

Comment: That's really tricky and for sure there is nothing build in for that. Are you sure there is no other way to get the information you want? How is the string build? Is this purely user input or is it created by code?

Comment: Would there be more than two colours in the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another version:

```
Sub GroupNumbersByColor()

    Dim c As Range, c2 As Range, num, pos As Long, txt As String
    Dim dict As Object, clr As Long, k, sep As String, ch As String
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    
    Set c = ActiveSheet.Range("D13") 'for example
    txt = c.Value & " " 'dodge to avoid ending on a digit...
    num = ""
    For pos = 1 To Len(txt)
        ch = Mid(txt, pos, 1)
        If ch Like "#" Then 'numeric?
            clr = c.Characters(pos, 1).Font.Color 'get the font color
            '... assuming all digits of each number share the same font color
            If Not dict.Exists(clr) Then dict.Add clr, New Collection 'new color?
            num = num & ch 'build up the number
        Else
            If Len(num) > 0 Then dict(clr).Add num 'capture previous number
            num = ""
        End If
    Next pos
    
    'write the grouped numbers out to the next column
    Set c2 = c.Offset(0, 1)
    c2.ClearContents
    For Each k In dict           'k=text color
        For Each num In dict(k)  'all numbers for this color
            AppendTextWithColor c2, sep, vbBlack
            AppendTextWithColor c2, CStr(num), CLng(k)
            sep = ","
        Next num
    Next k
End Sub

'Append text to a cell, and set the text's color
Sub AppendTextWithColor(c As Range, txt As String, clr As Long)
    If Len(txt) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    c.Characters(c.Characters.Count + 1, Len(txt)).Insert txt
    c.Characters(c.Characters.Count - (Len(txt) - 1), Len(txt)).Font.Color = clr
End Sub
```

Comment: If you want the grouped items to be sorted, then you could consider using Arraylists in place of the Collections and sort them as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50062146/478884

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the text to process is in cell N23, and the result need in P23.

The separator character is `,` (comma)

The result keep the original color of the values.

```
Sub sepcolor()

Set inp = Range("N23")
Set target = Range("P23")
Dim colorcoll As New Collection, blackcoll As New Collection
i = 1
Do
  On Error Resume Next
  comma = WorksheetFunction.Find(",", inp, i)
  If Err = 0 Then
    num = Mid(inp, i, comma - i)
    If inp.Characters(i, 1).Font.Color <> 0 Then
      colorcoll.Add Array(num, inp.Characters(i, 1).Font.Color)
    Else
      blackcoll.Add num
    End If
  i = comma + 1
  Else
    num = Mid(inp, comma + 1)
    If inp.Characters(comma + 1, 1).Font.Color <> 0 Then
      colorcoll.Add Array(num, inp.Characters(i + 1, 1).Font.Color)
    Else
      blackcoll.Add num
    End If
    Exit Do
  End If
  On Error GoTo 0
Loop While i <= Len(inp)
For i = 1 To colorcoll.Count
  restext = restext & "," & colorcoll(i)(0)
Next i
For i = 1 To blackcoll.Count
  restext = restext & "," & blackcoll(i)
Next i
target.Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
target.Value = Mid(restext, 2)
j = 1
For i = 1 To colorcoll.Count
  comma = WorksheetFunction.Find(",", target, j)
  target.Characters(j, comma - j).Font.Color = colorcoll(i)(1)
  j = comma + 1
Next i

End Sub
```