# Generate list from strings and numbers vba

Tags: vba, excel, combinations

This question is based on this puzzle that I am trying to do in vba: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/166765/fun-with-strings-and-numbers

Basically we have strings in col A and numbers in column B and in column C we have to generate a list so that:

1. The total count of any string should be exactly equal to its
   corresponding number in the input data.
2. No string should be repeated adjacently in the sequence, and every
   string should appear in the output list.
3. The selection of the next string should be done randomly as long as
   they don't break above two rules. Each solution should have a
   non-zero probability of being chosen.
4. If no combination is possible, the output should be just 0.

I tried this but I don't how to solve the problem so that it doesn't break rule #2. Any input would be appreciated thanks.

```
Sub generateList()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim fI As Long, totTimes As Long, i As Long, j As Long, fO As Long, tryCount As Long
Dim myArr()
Dim randNum As Long

OUT.Range("A1:A" & OUT.Rows.Count).Clear
fO = 1

With DATA
    fI = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If fI < 2 Then MsgBox "No data!": Exit Sub

    .Sort.SortFields.Clear
    .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B2:B" & fI), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With DATA.Sort
        .SetRange DATA.Range("A1:B" & fI)
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    fI = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If fI < 2 Then MsgBox "No data!": Exit Sub

    totTimes = 0: j = 0
    For i = 2 To fI
        If Trim(.Range("A" & i).Value) <> "" And IsNumeric(.Range("B" & i).Value) Then j = j + 1
    Next i
    If j < 1 Then MsgBox "No valid data present. Make sure column B has numbers and column A some string.": Exit Sub

    ReDim Preserve myArr(1 To j, 1 To 2)
    j = 0
    For i = 2 To fI
        If Trim(.Range("A" & i).Value) <> "" And IsNumeric(.Range("B" & i).Value) Then
            totTimes = totTimes + CLng(.Range("B" & i).Value)
            j = j + 1
            myArr(j, 1) = .Range("A" & i)
            myArr(j, 2) = .Range("B" & i)
        End If
    Next i


    Do While totTimes > 0

        randNum = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, j)

        If myArr(randNum, 2) > 0 Then
            totTimes = totTimes - 1
            OUT.Range("A" & fO) = myArr(randNum, 1)
            myArr(randNum, 2) = myArr(randNum, 2) - 1
            fO = fO + 1
        End If

tryAgain:
    Loop

End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
OUT.Activate
MsgBox "Process Completed"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution (that isn't based on yours, unfortunately) that gives correct results... some of the time. I think I know why it falls short, I just have given up on fixing it.

It's also terrible for golfing, since it's a rather large amount of code, and it's an unholy mishmash of different approaches and implementation ideas that I made up as I went (and I never cleaned it up properly)... but maybe some of this will inspire you to get further.

As per rule #3, I select each letter at random. It was hit and miss using only that approach so I moved to weighted probabilities, which is what the code further down uses - and it seems to work somewhat well. Occasionally there will be 1 letter too many for one of the elements, or there will be adjacent equal elements, so it doesn't actually solve the puzzle all the time.

Ideas to remedy this problem:

- Adjust the probability weights based on the frequency each letter has already been used. If you set `dbg` to true, you'll see that I implemented some calculations with that in mind, but never got around to figuring out how to actually adjust the weights themselves.
- Hardcode a check or two for how many letters have been used early in the result, for the largest element group
- Change the `rand` section to make more than 1 pass (maybe best out of 3) - the weights are sorted by "size", so doing 3 (or `n`) passes should increasingly favor the larger element groups

Maybe a combination of the first and the last suggestion.

Here's the code:

```
Sub NonRepeatSort(v() As String)
    Dim lElementCount As Long
    Dim lElement As Element ' Largest
    Dim tElement As Long ' Total element count
    Dim tEleGroups As Long ' Number of groups of elements

    Dim tEle As Element
    Dim e As Element
    Dim EleCol As New Collection

    Dim dbg As Boolean
    dbg = False

    Dim s As String, res As String, previousRes As String, inputString As String
    Dim lCounter As Long

    For i = 1 To UBound(v)
        ' Check if element already exists
        On Error Resume Next
            s = ""
            s = EleCol.Item(v(i, 1))
        On Error GoTo 0

        ' If not, create new
        If s = "" Then
            Set tEle = New Element
            With tEle
                .SetName = v(i, 1)
                .SetTotal = CLng(v(i, 2))
            End With

            EleCol.Add Item:=tEle, Key:=tEle.Name
        End If
    Next i

    For Each e In EleCol
        ' Find the largest element
        If e.Total > lElementCount Then
            lElementCount = e.Total
            Set lElement = e
        End If

        ' Count total elements
        tElement = tElement + e.Total

        ' And groups
        tEleGroups = tEleGroups + 1

        ' Generate inputstring
        For k = 1 To e.Total
            inputString = inputString + e.Name
        Next k
    Next e

    ' If the largest element is larger than the total remaining elements, we'll break rule 4
    If lElement.Total - (tElement - lElement.Total) > 1 Then
        Debug.Print "0"
        GoTo EndForSomeReason
    End If

    ' Bubble sort - lowest to highest
    ' Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/3588073/4604845
    Dim tmpE As Element
    For x = 1 To EleCol.Count - 1
        For y = 1 To EleCol.Count
            If EleCol.Item(x).Total > EleCol.Item(y).Total Then
                Set tmpE = EleCol.Item(y)
                EleCol.Remove y
                EleCol.Add tmpE, tmpE.Name, x
            End If
        Next y
    Next x

    ' Weighted probability array
    Dim pArr() As Variant, tmpProb As Double
    ReDim Preserve pArr(1 To 2, 1 To EleCol.Count)
    For u = 1 To UBound(pArr, 2)
        Set pArr(2, u) = EleCol.Item(u)
        tmpProb = tmpProb + pArr(2, u).Freq(tElement)
        pArr(1, u) = tmpProb
    Next u

    ' The meat of it
    Dim r As Long, lBool As Boolean, sLen As Long, o As Double, t As Long

    For j = 1 To tElement
        Do
            ' Reset loop control
            lBool = False

            ' Generate a random number between 1 and 100 _
                to decide which group we pick a letter from
            r = Rand1To100

            For i = 1 To UBound(pArr, 2)
                If r <= pArr(1, i) And Not r > pArr(1, i) Then
                    If dbg Then Debug.Print "Probability match: " & pArr(2, t).Name
                    t = i
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next i

            Set tEle = EleCol.Item(t)

            If dbg Then Debug.Print "Name: " & tEle.Name

            ' If the random group is different from the previous result, proceed
            If tEle.Name <> previousRes Then
                lBool = True
            Else
                If dbg Then Debug.Print "This was also the previous result - skipping"
            End If

            ' If the use-frequency for the random group is lower than _
                how many times it appears in the string, proceed
            If lBool Then
                o = Round((tEle.Used / tElement) * 100, 5)

                If dbg Then Debug.Print "Freq: " & tEle.Freq(tElement)
                If dbg Then Debug.Print "Used: " & tEle.UsedFreqI()
                If dbg Then Debug.Print "res%: " & Round((Len(res) / tElement) * 100, 1)
                If dbg Then Debug.Print "o   : " & o

                ' check use-frequency against modeled frequency
                If o < tEle.Freq(tElement) Then
                    If dbg Then Debug.Print "Proceed with " & tEle.Name
                    lBool = True
                Else
                    lBool = False
                End If
            End If

            If dbg Then Debug.Print "----------"
            lCounter = lCounter + 1
        Loop While (Not lBool And lCounter < 1000)

        tEle.IncrementUsed
        res = res + tEle.Name
        previousRes = tEle.Name
    Next j

    ' Generate results
    Debug.Print "INPUT : " & inputString
    Debug.Print "RESULT: " & res

EndForSomeReason:
End Sub


Function Rand1To100() As Long
    Dim r As Long

    Randomize
    r = ((100 - 1) * Rnd + 1)
    r = Round(r, 0)

    Rand1To100 = r
End Function


Private Sub TestSort()
    Dim v(1 To 4, 1 To 2) As String
    v(1, 1) = "A"
    v(1, 2) = "6"

    v(2, 1) = "B"
    v(2, 2) = "2"

    v(3, 1) = "C"
    v(3, 2) = "2"

    v(4, 1) = "D"
    v(4, 2) = "4"

    Call NonRepeatSort(v)
End Sub
```

And you'll need this class module:

```
' * Class module named Element

Private pName As String
Private pTotal As Long
Private pUsed As Long
Private FrequencyCoefficient As Long ' Obsolete?

' Name
Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = pName
End Property
Public Property Let SetName(s As String)
    pName = s
End Property

' Total
Public Property Get Total() As Long
    Total = pTotal
End Property
Public Property Let SetTotal(t As Long)
    pTotal = t
End Property

' Used
Public Property Get Used() As Long
    Used = pUsed
End Property
Public Sub IncrementUsed()
    pUsed = pUsed + 1
End Sub

' Freq coefficient
Public Property Get Freq(f As Long) As Double
    ' Where f is the total number of elements
    'Freq = FrequencyCoefficient
    Freq = Round((Me.Total / f) * 100, 5)
End Property

Private Property Let SetFreq(f As Long)
    ' Obsolete?
    ' Where f is the total number of elements
    FrequencyCoefficient = Round((Me.Total / f) * 100)
End Property

' Used freq - internal
Public Property Get UsedFreqI() As Long

    If Me.Used > 0 Then
        UsedFreqI = Round((Me.Used / Me.Total) * 100)
        'Debug.Print "UF: " & UsedFreqI
    Else
        UsedFreqI = 0
    End If
End Property

' Used freq - external
Public Property Get UsedFreqE(f As Long) As Long
    If Me.Used > 0 Then
        UsedFreq = Round((Me.Used / f) * 100)
    Else
        UsedFreq = 0
    End If
End Property
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I debug this I get user defined type not defined for the  `Dim lElement As Element ' Largest`

Comment: Did you add the class module? I'll edit to make it more clear.