# Sort a dictionary by a nested dictionary's items

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary, nested-lists

I have sample data in Excel:

[image]

Trying to get Top-3 elements (names) by **Salary** and Top-3 elements (names) by **Revenue**.

---

In **Visual Basic (VBA)** I created dictionary with Name as a `Key` and nested dictionary as `Item`

Nested dictionary have "`Salary`", "`Revenue`" and "`Position`" as **Keys**. And corresponding values as **Items**.

I created Dictionary as follows:

```
Dim MainDict As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim NestedDict As Scripting.Dictionary
    
Dim rngRange As Range
Set rngRange = wsMainWorkSheet.Range("B2:E8")

Dim rowCounter As Long
  
For rowCounter = 1 To rngRange.Rows.Count
    Set NestedDict = New Dictionary
    NestedDict.Add key:="Salary", Item:=rngRange(rowCounter, 2)
    NestedDict.Add key:="Revenue", Item:=rngRange(rowCounter, 3)
    NestedDict.Add key:="Position", Item:=rngRange(rowCounter, 4)
    
    Dim mainKey As String
    mainKey = CStr(rngRange(rowCounter, 1))
    If MainDict.Exists(mainKey) = False Then
        MainDict.Add key:=mainKey, Item:=NestedDict
    Else:
        MainDict.Item(mainKey)("Salary") = MainDict.Item(mainKey)("Salary") + rngRange(rowCounter, 2)
        MainDict.Item(mainKey)("Revenue") = MainDict.Item(mainKey)("Salary") + rngRange(rowCounter, 3)
    End If
Next rowCounter
```

---

Now If I print `Key, Items` in the Dictionary by the code:

```
Sub PrintDictionary(dict As Dictionary)
Dim key As Variant, subKey As Variant

For Each key In dict.Keys
    Debug.Print vbNewLine; "Name: " & key
    For Each subKey In dict(key).Keys
        Debug.Print subKey & ": " & dict(key)(subKey)
    Next subKey
Next key
End Sub
```

**Result:**

> Name: Name1
> Salary: 400
> Revenue: 5000
> Position: Manager

> Name: Name2
> Salary: 500
> Revenue: 25000
> Position: Associate

*(first 2 shown only)*

---

But I can't figure out the following:

- How to Get Top-3 elements (names) of the list by largest salaries ("**Salary**" key in nested dict).
- How to Get Top-3 elements (names) of the list by largest revenues ("**Revenue**" key in nested dict).

Is it possible to do sorting main dictionary based on nested dictionary's items in VBA without presorting data in the Excel table itself? Is it possible to sort data in such structures for further use later?

***Book1.xlsm** (sample data) is available on DropBox: [Book1.xlsm](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/ecor8lt5ynq1crk6m8lqs/Book1.xlsm?rlkey=mi7d8bdfyxamynkiskghdn96j&dl=0)*

Comment: `Dict` object doesn't have bulit-in `sort` method. `ADO` is a suitable method. Tim's code might be helpful for you too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66810171/in-excel-vba-how-can-you-sort-a-dictionary-by-a-field-of-the-item-similar-to-c

Comment: What does `"How to get..."` mean, what is the expected result, a one-based 2D array, another nested dictionary, or...? Please accurately describe what is expected and its purpose i.e. what you're planning to do with it.

Comment: Basically, I have a table shown in picture above. I used dictionary with nested dictionary for storing Name as Keys and all other Parameters as Items. I need to sort this data in main dictionary, retreive first 3 elements from this dictionary (by 3 largest Salaries) as a 2D Array and paste it on my Excel Sheet in Descending order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `ADO` is a suitable method for retrieving the TOP x records.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ADO_TOP()
    Dim sSrcFile As String
    Dim sSrcSht As String
    Dim oRSCon As Object, sRSData As Object, sDBCon As String, sSQL As String
    Dim i As Long, sSrcRng As String
    sSrcFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    sSrcSht = "Sheet1"
    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        sDBCon = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
            "Data Source=" & sSrcFile & ";" & _
            "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES"";"
    Else
        sDBCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
            "Data Source=" & sSrcFile & ";" & _
            "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES"";"
    End If
    Set oRSCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set sRSData = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    ' Modify top-left cell ref of table as needed
    sSrcRng = sSrcSht & "$" & Sheets(sSrcSht).Range("B1").CurrentRegion.Address(0, 0)
    oRSCon.Open sDBCon
    sSQL = "SELECT TOP 3 * FROM (SELECT Name,Sum(Salary) as Salary, " & _
        "Sum(Revenue) as Revenue FROM [" & sSrcRng & "] GROUP BY Name) ORDER BY Salary DESC "
    sRSData.Open sSQL, oRSCon, 0, 1, 1
    ' Write the output data to newsheet
    ' TOP 3 Salray
    Sheets.Add
    Range("A1") = "TOP 3 Salray"
    For i = 0 To sRSData.Fields.Count - 1
        Cells(3, i + 1).Value = sRSData.Fields(i).Name
    Next i
    Range("A4").CopyFromRecordset sRSData
    
    sRSData.Close: Set sRSData = Nothing
    oRSCon.Close: Set oRSCon = Nothing
End Sub
```

- For Top 3 Revenue

```
    sSQL = "SELECT TOP 3 * FROM (SELECT Name,Sum(Salary) as Salary, " & _
        "Sum(Revenue) as Revenue FROM [" & sSrcRng & "] GROUP BY Name) ORDER BY Revenue DESC "
```

[image]