# Why bubble sort is not efficient?

Tags: node.js, performance, sorting, assembly, bubble-sort

I am developing backend project using node.js and going to implement sorting products functionality.
I researched some articles and there were several articles saying bubble sort is not efficient. 
Bubble sort was used in my previous projects and I was surprised why it is bad.
Could anyone explain about why it is inefficient? 
If you can explain by c programming or assembler commands it would be much appreciated.

Comment: There are lots of O(n^2) sort algorithms (bubble sort, insertion sort, selection sort, etc.) that are mainly used for teaching purposes because they tend to be easier to understand than the better sort algorithms that people actually use.  Fast comparison-based sorting algorithms are O(n\*log(n)), which is the best that can be done for that type of sort.  Quicksort, merge sort, heap sort, and others are all O(n\*log(n)).

Comment: Hmmm, Never quite understand why folks use Bubble sort with its O(n^2) versus the speedy   [QB sort](http://wiki.c2.com/?QuantumBogoSort) with O(1).  

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Bubble Sort has O(N^2) time complexity so it's garbage for large arrays compared to O(N log N) sorts.

In JS, if possible use built-in sort functions that the JS runtime might be able to handle with pre-compiled custom code, instead of having to JIT-compile your sort function.  The standard library sort should (usually?) be well-tuned for the JS interpreter / JIT to handle efficiently, and use an efficient implementation of an efficient algorithm.

The rest of this answer is assuming a use-case like sorting an array of integers in an ahead-of-time compiled language like C compiled to native asm.  Not much changes if you're sorting an array of structs with one member as the key, although cost of compare vs. swap can vary if you're sorting `char*` strings vs. large structs containing an `int`.  (Bubble Sort is bad for any of these cases with all that swapping.)

---

**See [Bubble Sort: An Archaeological Algorithmic Analysis](https://users.cs.duke.edu/%7Eola/papers/bubble.pdf)** for more about why it's "popular" (or widely taught / discussed) despite being one the worst O(N^2) sorts, including some accidents of history / pedagogy.  Also including an interesting quantitative analysis of whether it's *actually* (as sometimes claimed) one of the easiest to write or understand using a couple code metrics.

For small problems where a simple O(N^2) sort is a reasonable choice (e.g. the N <= 32 element base case of a Quick Sort or Merge Sort), Insertion Sort is often used because it has good best-case performance (one quick pass in the already-sorted case, and efficient in almost-sorted cases).

A Bubble Sort (with an early-out for a pass that didn't do any swaps) is also not horrible in some almost-sorted cases but is worse than Insertion Sort.  But an element can only move toward the front of the list one step per pass, so **if the smallest element is near the end but otherwise fully sorted, it still takes Bubble Sort O(N^2) work**.  Wikipedia explains [Rabbits and turtles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort#Rabbits_and_turtles).

Insertion Sort doesn't have this problem: a small element near the end will get inserted (by copying earlier elements to open up a gap) efficiently once it's reached.  (And reaching it only requires comparing already-sorted elements to determine that and move on with zero actual insertion work).  A large element near the start will end up moving upwards quickly, with only slightly more work: each new element to be examined will have to be inserted *before* that large element, after all others.  So that's two compares and effectively a swap, unlike the one swap per step Bubble Sort would do in it's "good" direction.  Still, Insertion Sort's bad direction is vastly better than Bubble Sort's "bad" direction.

Fun fact: state of the art for small-array sorting on real CPUs can include SIMD Network Sorts using packed min/max instructions, and vector shuffles to do multiple "comparators" in parallel.

---

#### Why Bubble Sort is bad on real CPUs:

The pattern of swapping is probably more random than Insertion Sort, and less predictable for CPU branch predictors.  Thus leading to more branch mispredicts than Insertion Sort.

I haven't tested this myself, but think about how Insertion Sort moves data: each full run of the inner loop moves a group of elements to the right to open up a gap for a new element.  The size of that group might stay fairly constant across outer-loop iterations so there's a reasonable chance of predicting the pattern of the loop branch in that inner loop.

But Bubble Sort doesn't do so much creation of partially-sorted groups; the pattern of swapping is unlikely to repeat<sup>1</sup>.

I searched for support for this guess I just made up, and did find some: [Insertion sort better than Bubble sort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428336/insertion-sort-better-than-bubble-sort/10429351#10429351) quotes Wikipedia:

> Bubble sort also interacts poorly with modern CPU hardware. It produces at least twice as many writes as insertion sort, twice as many cache misses, and **asymptotically more branch mispredictions.**

(IDK if that "number of writes" was naive analysis based on the source, or looking at decently optimized asm):

That brings up another point: Bubble Sort can very easily compile into inefficient code.  **The notional implementation of swapping actually stores into memory, then re-reads that element it just wrote**.  Depending on how smart your compiler is, this might actually happen in the asm instead of reusing that value in a register in the next loop iteration.  In that case, you'd have store-forwarding latency inside the inner loop, creating a loop-carried dependency chain.  And also creating a potential bottleneck on cache read ports / load instruction throughput.

---

**Footnote 1:**  Unless you're sorting the same tiny array repeatedly; I tried that once on my Skylake CPU with a simplified x86 asm implementation of Bubble Sort I wrote for [this code golf question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77836/sort-an-integer-list/149038#149038) (the code-golf version is intentionally horrible for performance, optimized only for machine-code size; IIRC the version I benchmarked avoided store-forwarding *stalls* and `lock`ed instructions like `xchg mem,reg`).

I found that with the same input data every time (copied with a few SIMD instructions in a repeat loop), the IT-TAGE branch predictors in Skylake "learned" the whole pattern of branching for a specific ~13-element Bubble Sort, leading to `perf stat` reporting under 1% branch mispredicts, IIRC.  So it didn't demonstrate the tons of mispredicts I was expecting from Bubble Sort after all, until I increased the array size some. :P

Answer (score 1):

Bubble sort runs in O(n^2) time complexity. Merge sort takes O(n*log(n)) time, while quick sort takes O(n*log(n)) time on average, thus performing better than bubble sort.

Refer to this: [complexity of bubble sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29555839/how-to-calculate-bubble-sort-time-complexity).

Comment: It's also the worst O(n^2) sort, including being bad for almost-sorted arrays.  For small problems where a simple O(n^2) sort is a reasonable choice (e.g. the base case of Quick Sort or Merge Sort), Insertion Sort is usually used.  See [Bubble Sort: An Archaeological Algorithmic Analysis](https://users.cs.duke.edu/~ola/papers/bubble.pdf)