# For comparison in speed between C and Assembly language using bubble sort, which of it in general is faster?

Tags: c, performance, assembly, optimization, bubble-sort

I have researched bubble sort speed differences between C and Assembly language, and found that code optimization is one factor.

What other factors are there to consider for bubble sort speed differences between C and Assembly language and which tends to be faster?

Comment: Extending to the answers given so far (question closed already): C compilers do a really good job in optimising, as denoted already, and you need to be a really good expert in ASM *and* the specific machine you are writing for to achieve similarly good output. Most humans way not as good as as the compiler, and even if, it's usually just not worth all the effort! There *are* situations you still *can* profit from ASM, though.

Comment: Typical scenario: You *profile* your application first (!!!) and discover a specific function being a bottleneck in execution time or (depending on what you intend to optimise for) in memory consumption. Then you let the compiler emit ASM code instead of machine code, and on this basis you try to optimise further *for this one specific use case* the code generated by the compiler optimised for the *general, i.e. any arbitrary, use case* resulted in not being efficient enough. Again: You need deep background knowledge about machine and algorithm to be able to do so!

Comment: @Aconcagua: 100% agreed with the "not worth the effort" point, especially when there's much more to gain from changing the algorithm (to anything other than Bubble Sort).  As someone who *is* capable of noticing missed-optimizations in compiler output, I still wouldn't consider sending in patches to software projects like glibc with hand-written asm versions of most functions that didn't already have one, because it's not worth the maintenance burden.  (And might not be faster on some future CPU of the same architecture, especially once compilers improve.)

Comment: I think the best comment on this page is the most true which is if you know exactly what you are doing it will never be slower than C.   Compilers like gcc have been getting worse over time gcc 4.x.x is better than anything that came after (for certain targets).  You can almost always find a number of optimizations in the output of the compiler, some of those are of course the compiler is limited to the rules of the C language and asm has no rules, limited only to the logic/hardware rules.

Comment: BUT if you dont try you will never understand this, and if nobody tries there will be no more compilers much less processors or bootloaders, the devices will be the charcoal on the end of burnt sticks writing on rocks.

Comment: No matter what the algorithm for that algorithm asm will always be at or faster than the compiler (in the right hands).  In the wrong hands asm could be anywhere from faster to significantly slower.  Dont even need to do the tests to know what the result of the tests are for this question.  Other factors are that the compiler does not know the system only the architecture, so if you know the system (speeds of the memory, etc) you can sometimes make the compiled code faster but also the asm.

Comment: The C version alone can have widely ranging performance values based on the skills of the author and the knowledge of that target and that specific compilers nuances.  This is the problem with benchmarks the fantasy that the same (high level language) code runs the same on the same machine or similar machines when the same code can be several times faster or slower on the same machine, much less be used to measure against other machines.

Answer (score 3):

C gets converted to assembly by the compiler and these days the compiler does a very good job, to the point of being faster than a very experienced human, even with infinite time in their hands.

It is not only a matter of which instructions to use but also their order. These days CPUs have multiple internal resources and the compiler knows how to optimize them such that it maximizes throughput. Memory loads and stores are also explicitly optimized.

In that sense, the assembly code that works the fastest for one CPU architecture, might be sluggish for another architecture, even inside the same family (eg Intel). So the C language works as a general template for algorithm correctness and all the hard work of optimization gets done by the compiler underneath. This optimization work is typically better done by a machine.

So overall Id say that apart from very specific cases like very SIMD heavy  algorithms in audio/video or cryptography, C (with a modern compiler) is always the winner.

Comment: Compilers like gcc have been getting worse over time not better, and to use the word "always", in an decent sized project you can always find the output of the compiler can be optimized or improved.  But, yes you have to know what you are doing.  And until you do, post questions on a site like this...IMO the reason the compilers are getting worse is because folks are told to stick to high level and avoid learning asm.   Each year fewer and fewer able to actually make a functional compiler much less optimizers.

Comment: the compiler has no idea about the system, speeds of the memory choosing between extra instructions to build/compute a value vs loading that value from a pool, etc.   We have not been processor bound for a while, and the compiler has no clue how to optimize for the system.

Comment: Worse? Nonsense. GCC beats clang/LLVM by a large margin nowadays. And saying that gcc 4.7 performs better than gcc 13.0 is just preposterous. The number and quality of passes is exceedingly better than ten years ago.

Comment: @old_timer From your statement I can see you have zero idea of all the developments that took place in the past 10 years. Compilers today have a complete model of every sub-architecture even before it is launched. They optimize ALU, memory load/stores, and vector resources before converting from IR into assembly. That's what the '-march' and '-mtune' options are for. I suggest you read more, you need to catch up with compiler technology. Here is a start:  https://llvm.org/devmtg/2014-10/Slides/Estes-MISchedulerTutorial.pdf

Comment: Compilers do continue to improve on the whole / on average, but they're far from perfect.  They don't have a "complete model" of every microarchitecture.  They have some tuning settings, and maybe a table of throughput and latency, but missed optimizations are still common.  e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/7xvGY3YYe shows GCC13 getting the tuning exactly backwards, compiling `*short_ptr = 1234;` to `mov eax, 1234` / `mov [rdi], ax` to avoid LCP stalls which don't exist for MOV on Sandybridge-family.  But `*short_ptr += 1234;` compiles to `add word [rdi], 1234` where the imm16 will LCP stall.

Comment: Compilers do continue to improve on the whole / on average, but they're far from perfect. They don't have a "complete model" of every microarchitecture. They have some tuning settings, and maybe a table of throughput and latency, but missed optimizations are still common. e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/hPznoa65x shows GCC13 avoiding LCP stalls for `mov` but not `add` with an `imm16`, compiling `*short_ptr = 1234;` to `mov eax, 1234` / `mov [rdi], ax`, but `+=` to `add word [rdi], 1234`.

Comment: ([Agner Fog says](https://agner.org/optimize/microarchitecture.pdf#page=151) `mov` doesn't have LCP stalls on Sandybridge-family including Skylake, but testing on my Skylake i7-6700k shows that's incorrect, I do get counts for `ild_stall.lcp` even with `mov ax, 1234`, the specific example he used.)  Anyway, if it's worth avoiding for `mov`, it should be worth avoiding for `add`.  I could point to any number of other examples, like GCC using xor-zeroing to break the false dependency for `lz/tzcnt` even though that's fixed on SKL, but not for the true output dependency in `bsr`/`bsf`.

Comment: old_timer qualified their claim under the question, that GCC has only been getting worse for some architectures (I'd guess they're talking about embedded ARM).  I don't know if that's true, or what evidence they're basing that on, but at least it's less trivial to disprove by pointing to major improvements in auto-vectorization for x86.

Comment: Another example of GCC not using what it supposedly knows about microarchitectures is [gcc optimization flag -O3 makes code slower than -O2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28875325) - it puts a `cmov` in the critical path of a loop-carried dep chain, even when you write the source with just a `+=` on the critical path.  This is GCC bug https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=82666 , a regression in GCC7, still not fixed.  (Although GCC13 auto-vectorizes the loop even with SSE2, which avoids the problem unless you use `-fno-tree-vectorize`.)

Comment: Your edit introducing the 3rd paragraph was a big improvement, but I still disagree with the first paragraph; it's wildly over-optimistic.  IDK if there'd be anything to improve on in GCC or clang's code-gen for bubble sort if compiling C that was already optimized to hint the compiler towards efficient asm, but in many other cases like the one I linked in my last comment, and [Why does C++ code for testing the Collatz conjecture run faster than hand-written assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40354978), I can write faster asm for my Skylake CPU than compilers make, for a single tight loop.

Comment: Not always *much* faster, but definitely sometimes, even for scalar code.  And if we're talking about auto-vectorized portable C vs. hand-vectorized code for x86, that's another common source of speedups for non-trivial stuff, especially things with mixed element sizes, or anything not totally straightforward.  (Manual vectorization with C intrinsics can usually compile to optimal asm, so IDK whether to count that.)  Anyway, unless you're considering "very experienced" as not the highest skill level, compilers aren't faster than what any human can do with unlimited time for a single loop.

Comment: Clever humans can always use compiler output as a starting point, unless they see a better strategy entirely.  Where compilers do well is inlining across large code-bases, to create asm that would be unmaintainable.  So in that sense, yes, compilers can do better than humans practically can for non-tiny amounts of code.  But this question was about a single small function with 2 nested loops, Bubble Sort.  On that scale, the most skilled humans are more than able to compete with compilers.

Comment: (Across different microarchitectures, any given build usually can't be optimal for all microaches; as you say, what's fast one one could be slow on another.  And avoiding one uarch's potholes can mean a slight slowdown everywhere else.  e.g. extra code-size from padding instructions to avoid Skylake's JCC erratum, perhaps lowering decode throughput on Core 2 or Bulldozer which don't have a uop cache.)

Answer (score 3):

CPUs run machine code.  A C compiler can make machine code for you from C source, vs. with assembly language you're making all the important decisions yourself.

---

The most important factor is that Bubble Sort is a bad algorithm you should basically never use, especially when you care about performance (*[Why bubble sort is not efficient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61997897/why-bubble-sort-is-not-efficient)*).  (Only sometimes if you care about tiny code size, like code golf  [Sort an Integer List](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/149038)).

Other than that, if you know exactly what you're doing in asm, it will never be slower than C, and you can control micro-optimization choices like the ones that led to GCC making a very slower bubble sort when trying to auto-vectorize.  See *[Bubble sort slower with -O3 than -O2 with GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69503317/bubble-sort-slower-with-o3-than-o2-with-gcc)* for the details of that case.

But if you *don't* know asm and CPU architecture in that level of detail, you're unlikely to improve on compiler output.  **There is no "generally" that's true across all CPU (micro-)architectures and all programmer skill-levels.**

Related: *[Why does C++ code for testing the Collatz conjecture run faster than hand-written assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40354978/why-does-c-code-for-testing-the-collatz-conjecture-run-faster-than-hand-writte)* - another example of the kinds of beginner mistakes that can make your asm even slower than a debug build of a C program.

---

If you cared about making a sort function run fast, the first thing you'd change would be the algorithm, to Insertion Sort or something.
Or a SIMD sorting network, especially if you're writing in non-portable assembly language in the first place.

So this question only makes sense if there's something forcing you to use a bad algorithm like Bubble Sort.  Or if you aren't aiming for performance in the first place and are making arbitrary choices of algorithm. Or don't know that Bubble Sort is slow, in which case we should definitely make pessimistic assumptions about programmer skill at assembly language.  (Assembly language performance is even more sensitive than most languages to programmer skill at optimizing.)

But if someone forced you to spend time optimizing Bubble Sort, with asm you could probably optimize the case where an element bubbles a long way, maybe avoiding a store/reload as part of a loop-carried dependency chain. But you could probably do the same thing in C with a `tmp` variable, so IDK whether to count it.

You'd only *think* of doing that in C if you were aware of the asm / CPU-architecture reasons for it, but often you can get a compiler to generate the efficient asm you want by changing the C. That's usually best because it's still portable C.

Answer (score 0):

**Practically, there really isn't much of a speed difference.**

While it is true that Assembly allows you to directly access individual registers on the CPU and that this might allow you to make some small optimisations, humans typically aren't good at seeing such small optimisations.

For that reason, it's usually better (or at least, not slower) to just program in C and allow the compiler to optimise it. Even without very low-level access, C compilers typically can optimise a program better than a human could in Assembly.

Comment: *Practically, there really isn't much of a speed difference.* - That's not true in general.  There are certainly counter-examples for other algorithms, where novice mistakes in asm can make things way slower than an optimizing C compiler.  Or an asm implementation optimized for code-size can be much slower. It's easy to imagine a naive Bubble Sort in x86 asm that used `xchg mem, reg` as part of the swap, and thus was *much* slower than what a compiler would do.  (In fact I don't have to image; people have posted such answers on SO.) (`xchg mem,reg` has an implicit `lock` prefix on 386 and up.)

Comment: Also, if anyone actually cared about Bubble Sort performance and you were forbidden from just implementing Insertion Sort instead (or a SIMD sorting network), with asm you could probably optimize the case where an element bubbles a long way, maybe avoiding a store/reload as part of a loop-carried dependency chain.  But you could probably do the same thing in C with a tmp variable, so IDK whether to count it.  You'd only *think of* doing that in C if you were aware of the asm / CPU-architecture reasons for it, though.

Comment: I used to write hand-written assembly up to 10 years ago when LLVM took off - and brought GCC with it - into optimizing passes. After some time, I realized my hand written assembly was often slower because of non-optimized instruction pressure and badly placed load/stores. Just not worth it anymore.